# Odroid: can it run python code to use GPIO pins?

Tags: python, odroid

I'm planning to get either Odroid C2 or RaspberryPi 3 and I'm just wondering because when I search for tutorials on how to use GPIO pins in Odroid I'm seing codes written in C I guess? I just want to ask if I can use python code to use the GPIO pins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Odroid.com has your answer at:

http://odroid.com/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=en:c1_tinkering

You need to follow the instructions to download/build/install the WiringPi library 'C' library first, and then the Python Wrappers will can be installed.  The sample program shows how to exercise LEDs and read the Analog/Digital converter.

I installed on their ubuntu64 image without issue.

Answer (score -1):

odroid/ orange pi and all the other SBC on the market suck, why making a product with a header of 40 pins, when it is virtually impossible to access them.It is just a expensive waiste of time.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).